# Why isn't my rewrite rule working when there is no second parameter?

Tags: rewrite-rules, regex, rewrite-tag

Here is my rewrite rule code:

```
add_rewrite_rule('tides/([^/]+)/([^/]*)', 'index.php?page_id=4348&location=$matches[1]&month=$matches[2]', 'top');
add_rewrite_tag('%location%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%month%', '([^&]*)');
```

This works great for the following URL:

```
/tides/mylocation/mymonth/
```

but 404's on the following:

```
/tides/mylocation/
```

I'm flushing the rewrite rules every time I change the code. I tried changing `*` to `+` but no help there.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Some answers were suggesting adding another rewrite rule so I added:

```
add_rewrite_rule('tides/([^/]+)/$', 'index.php?page_id=4348&location=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

before my other rule, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is requiring the last slash be present which it will not be by default. So the path `tides/mylocation/` is shortened to `tides/mylocation` and then tested. Instead, wrap the last part in an optional group using the `?` and update the match number.

```
add_rewrite_rule('tides/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?', 'index.php?page_id=4348&location=$matches[1]&month=$matches[3]', 'top');
```

Comment: That was absolutely the problem, thank you so much! Even though my permalinks end in a slash, they still get stripped before applying the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example URL doesn't match the pattern you defined in your rewrite rule. You need to add another rule to match URLs with just a single path element.

Comment: I used http://regexpal.com/ to test the regex and monkeyman rewrite analyzer to test it in wordpress, and it does seem to match. Doesn't the * make the second param optional?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial tides rewrite rule is looking for two parameters. If you want it to accept different combinations of parameters, you need to specify those rules.

For example, these are two rules from the base Wordpress install:

`search/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$ => index.php?s=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
search/(.+)/?$ => index.php?s=$matches[1]`

Comment: Is there any way to match a blank parameter?

Comment: You could try doing an 'or' inside of the parameter, and match a possible empty string. For example: ([0-9]|^$)